# Can't check null in Java

Tags: java

I wrote this code and I cannot understand why I can't check for a null in an array.

```
public static int[] maxArr(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] newArray = new int[Math.max(a.length, b.length)];
    int min = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            if (a[i] >= b[i]) {
                newArray[i]=a[i];
            } else {
                newArray[i]=b[i];
            }
        }




        for (int j = min; j < newArray.length; j++) {
            if (b[min] == null) {
                newArray[j] = a[j];
            }
            else {
                newArray[j] = b[j];
            }
        }

        return newArray;
        }
```

This is the error:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
            if (b[min] == null) {
                       ^
first type:  int
second type: <null>
1 error
```

I am new to programming so Thanks in advance

Comment: My Java array knowledge is rusty, but can a null even be added to a primitive `int` array?

Comment: You can't compare native int with null. If you want to allow null values in array or compare with the elements of array, you need to use wrapper class Integer

Comment: Did you try to create an empty array and use System.out.println(...) to display the value at index 0, to see what is contained in the array? Once you see the default value did you then try to assign null to the array? Don't assume things when programming. Do some simple debugging to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said you can't compare primitive integers to null, you may take another approach to achieve the same.

Your first loop is fine and for copying the remaining integers from the larger array you may use System.arraycopy method. You can modify your method to something like this,

```
public static int[] maxArr(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int[] newArray = new int[Math.max(a.length, b.length)];
    int min = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= b[i]) {
            newArray[i] = a[i];
        } else {
            newArray[i] = b[i];
        }
    }

    if (a.length > b.length) {
        System.arraycopy(a, min, newArray, min, a.length - min);
    } else {
        System.arraycopy(b, min, newArray, min, b.length - min);
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

This also gives you the same effect as you wanted to do through second for loop.

Try testing it with following code,

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int[] a = new int[] { 2, 7, 2, 8 };
    int[] b = new int[] { 4, 6, 3, 9, 5, 8, 7};
    int[] max = maxArr(a, b);

    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(max).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

This prints following output as you desire,

```
[4, 7, 3, 9, 5, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have array of primitive type `int`. And primitives can never have `null` value. By default `int` variable will have `0` value assigned. You may need to switch to wrapper class `Integer` to be able to use `null` to check for not initialized value.

Comment: Can you please edit my question with an example ?
Since I am a new programmer I know nothing about wrapper.

Comment: @ShiriSadeh just replace `int` with `Integer` in your code and read about wrapper classes in Java